# Parsing an xml tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the next xml file  and I want to display the element from first

for example : when I select the  with value Xp I want to display the version 1.9 2.0 
or if I selected the system Win 10 to dispay the values 3.0 and 3.1
How can I parse this tag to extract the numbers  using javascript ?

```
<system> Xp
  <version>1.9</version>
  <version>2.0</version>
</system>

<system> Win10
  <version>3.0</version>
  <version>3.1</version>
</system>
```

Comment: your xml is not Proper use https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

Comment: Here i wrote sample code on JSFiddle check it. https://jsfiddle.net/tharukaCodeWorks/m3ugcd5j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml is not well formed. An xml element can have **either text or child elements** as content. Instead, try this

```
<system os="Xp">
  <version>1.9</version>
  <version>2.0</version>
</system>
```

or that

```
<system>
  <os>Xp</os>
  <version>1.9</version>
  <version>2.0</version>
</system>
```